# How to populate a SQL table column only the first time

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
string sSQL = @"UPDATE [MyTable1]
    SET AT09 = GETDATE()
    ,AT80 = 'IP'
    ,AT83 = 'CO'
    ,AT34 = GETDATE() //ONLY IF IT IS NOT EMPTY
    ,AT84 = '" + sU + "' WHERE AS = 0";
```

I have the above query in C# and what I am looking to do is update the `AT34` field only if it doesn't have a value.

So pretty much when the query runs first, it will add the current date but any consequent time, it will not (given the column is populated with the date)

How can I achieve that.

Comment: ...where at34 is not null?

Comment: his where clause is `WHERE AS = 0`, adding `at34 is not null` would update only a subset of those rows.

Comment: @1010 Yes, if AS = 0 then update the table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
string sSQL = @"UPDATE [MyTable1]
SET AT09 = GETDATE()
,AT80 = 'IP'
,AT83 = 'CO'
,AT34 = (CASE WHEN AT34 IS NULL THEN GETDATE() ELSE AT34 END)
,AT84 = '" + sU + "' WHERE AS = 0";
```

Comment: Thank you. They are all great answers but this is the complete one.

Answer (score 3):

```
string sSQL = @"UPDATE [MyTable1]
SET AT09 = GETDATE()
,AT80 = 'IP'
,AT83 = 'CO'
,AT34 = CASE WHEN AT34 IS NULL THEN GETDATE() ELSE AT34 END 
,AT84 = '" + sU + "' WHERE AS = 0";
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use this expression to assign at34's value

```
AT34 = ISNULL(AT34, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a case phrase that says : `AT34=` `Case When AT34 is null then GetDate() else AT34 End` in the place where you are using `AT34=GetDate()` now.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
string sSQL = @"UPDATE [MyTable1]
    SET AT09 = GETDATE()
    ,AT80 = 'IP'
    ,AT83 = 'CO'
    ,AT34 = CASE WHEN AT34 IS NOT NULL          
                            THEN GETDATE() 
                             ELSE AT34
                  END //ONLY IF IT IS NOT EMPTY
    ,AT84 = '" + sU + "'
WHERE AS = 0";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an isnull...

```
string sSQL = @"UPDATE [MyTable1]
SET AT09 = GETDATE()
,AT80 = 'IP'
,AT83 = 'CO'
,AT34 = ISNULL(AT34, GETDATE()) //ONLY IF IT IS NOT EMPTY
,AT84 = '" + sU + "' WHERE AS = 0";
```

...or call two update commands, both with where conditions. One where condition should check if the date is null, the other where condition checking if it isn't...

```
string sSQL = @"UPDATE [MyTable1]
SET AT09 = GETDATE()
,AT80 = 'IP'
,AT83 = 'CO'
,AT34 = GETDATE() //ONLY IF IT IS NOT EMPTY
,AT84 = '" + sU + "' WHERE AS = 0 AND AT34 IS NULL
    UPDATE [MyTable1]
SET AT09 = GETDATE()
,AT80 = 'IP'
,AT83 = 'CO'
,AT84 = '" + sU + "' WHERE AS = 0 AND AT34 IS NOT NULL";
```

Comment: I think in this case the two updates option would perform worse.

Comment: Depends on the size of the table. Unless it is huge, it wouldn't make a noticeable difference. But I agree the ISNULL approach is shorter and more readable

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you can do this by using C# condition also.

1. At first Run a query to get the row you want to update.
2. Check if the AT34 is empty or not.
3. If AT34 is empty then run the query as you write.
4. Else run the update query without the `AT34 = GETDATE()`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Variant 1: 
set AT34 = isnull(GETDATE(),AT34)

Variant 2:

set AT34 CASE 
 WHEN AT34 IS NULL
 THEN getdate()
 ELSE AT34
END